# HashMap getting unintended string for key value

Tags: java, hashmap

I have this piece of code :

```
private static void addItem(String[] commandParsed, Set<Item> inventory, Map<String, Map<String, Item>> maps) {
        Item item = new Item(commandParsed[1], Double.parseDouble(commandParsed[2]), commandParsed[3]);
        String mapName = commandParsed[3];
        Map<String, Item> map = new HashMap<>();
        if (inventory.contains(item)) {
            System.out.printf("Error: Item %s already exists%n", item.name);
        } else {
            inventory.add(item);
            System.out.printf("Ok: Item %s added successfully%n", item.name);
             maps.computeIfAbsent(mapName, k -> new HashMap<>()).put(item.name, item);
        }
    }
```

my Idea is to add all unique items to a set and then to make  `Map<String, Map<String, Item>> maps` where the key is the type of the added item and the value to be map containing all items of that type, but the key to be the Item names. However the keys of the inner maps are again the type of the item. here is some sample input

```
add CowMilk 1.90 dairy
add BulgarianYogurt 1.90 dairy
```

I am trying to find out why my inner map `key-value pair` is not `<item.name, Item>` but `<item.type, Item>` since my code is `.put(item.name, item);`

This is my Item class constructor

```
 public Item(String name, double price, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.type = type;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to ask the question.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do and what the issue you are facing is.

Comment: my bad, it should be clearer now

Comment: Can you give us an example of the parameter values that get passed to `addItem`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misreading the debugger object tree display.

Map entries are **key-value pairs**.

The `"dairy"` map entry is a key-value pair with key "dairy", and a value that is another map (with keys "CowMilk" and "BulgarianYogurt")

So it's not that the inner map has a "dairy" key, it's just that expanding the "dairy" map entry exposes "dairy" as the *key* in the map entry. The keys of the inner map are "CowMilk" and "BulgarianYogurt".

Comment: so it is inputting them as I intend them to, thank you I dont know how I got confused

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find out why my inner map key-value pair is not
> <item.name, Item> but <item.type, Item> since my code is
> .put(item.name, item);

You need to put {item.name, item} inside the inner map as shown below:

```
maps.computeIfAbsent(mapName, k -> new HashMap<String, Item>().put(item.name, item));
```

Comment: it did not fix it, I am adding a picture from the debbug